# Pass props to redux initial state

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to set the initial state in reducer.js from the existing props which I get from the Home.js

I tried to call `home: this.props.homedata` to set the initial state but it is not working.

```
import { COMMENT_SHOW, LIKE_SHOW, HOMEDATA_SHOW } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    wallid: '',
    comment: '',
    like: '',
    home: this.props.homedata
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
........///////////
}
```

Reducer.js

When the app loads I want to get the same data in home which I have in `homedata` state

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way, but you could call your action (which you would normally use to update home) in a lifecycle method like ComponentDidMount sending in those props.

Comment: I added if else condition to resolve the issue in mapststetoprops. If reducer returns homedata as blank then in my mapstatetoprops the homedata is assigned to current props, else it would get state from reducer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to pass prop to your reducer. What you can do is have a data set file, say `data.js`, and export your data. Import it into your reducer file, and set it as your initial data.

```
import { COMMENT_SHOW, LIKE_SHOW, HOMEDATA_SHOW } from '../actions/types';
import { homeData } from 'path/to/data';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    wallid: '',
    comment: '',
    like: '',
    home: homedata,
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
........///////////
}
```

If you don't want the sample data modified as the app runs. Maybe you need it to reset your home data, you will need to clone the data before passing it to into your initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Reducers don't have `props`. You probably picked it up from React.

A reducer should update the Redux state based on the dispatched actions. To update the state to be `homedata`, you can dispatch an action and return the data in the reducer as the new state.

```js
// action to dispatch
{
   type: "UPDATE_HOME",
   payload: homedata
}

// Reducer.js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    wallid: '',
    comment: '',
    like: '',
    home: {}
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_HOME":
      return {
        ...state,
        home: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: i added if else condition to resolve the issue. If reducer returns homedata as blank then in my mapstatetoprops the homedata is assigned to current props, else it would get state from reducer. btw thanks to help me out